# -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91da0f0

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

when i set the value in nsmutabledictionary then given error show in image below....

[image]

here my code for setvalue in nsmutabledictionary

```
NSMutableArray *countArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0;i<artistName.count;i++)
{
    int count=0;
    NSMutableDictionary *dir1=[artistName objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *artist1=[dir1 objectForKey:@"SONG_ARTIST"];

    for (int j=0;j<CurrentPlayingSong.count;j++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dir2=[CurrentPlayingSong objectAtIndex:j];
        NSString *artist2=[dir2 objectForKey:@"SONG_ARTIST"];

        if ([artist2 isEqualToString:artist1])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    NSString *Size=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",count];
    [dir1 setObject:Size forKey:@"SIZE"];

    [countArray addObject:dir1];
}
return countArray;
```

Comment: The error message is quite obvious, you'd have saved a few minutes if you googled it. Voting for close, there's no need for more dupes of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731353/nsdictionaryi-setobjectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: pls change NSString as NSMutableString, then try

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this `NSMutableDictionary *dir1=[artistName objectAtIndex:i];` returns a NSDictionary object which turns your dir1 to the same type.

best way is to do something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dir1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[artistName objectAtIndex:i]];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *dir1 = [artistName[i] mutableCopy];
```

This will ensure that dir1 will always be NSMutableDictionary.

hope this helps