# iOS: can't set the null value in an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set a value in an `NSMutableDictionary` but I'm always getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x10fd55990> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'
```

In the NSMutableDictionary I have an `@"image"` field that can be `null`. I want to replace the `null` value with a placeholder image name. 
This is how I do it:

```
NSMutableDictionary * item = self.carouselSource[index];
if([Utils isNull:[item valueForKey:@"image"]]) {
[item setValue:@"default_image.png" forKey:@"image"]; 
}
```

But the application crash in this line

```
[item setValue:@"default_image.png" forKey:@"image"];
```

due to the error above.

Comment: Use `fast enumration`

Comment: Your dictionary is immutable - it's an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSMutableDictionary`. for more information you can get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731353/nsdictionaryi-setobjectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik check my edit please

Comment: @Llg - can you update the question based on `NSMutableDictionary` modification

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I edited my question please check it

Comment: try this `NSMutableDictionary * item =  [self.carouselSource[index] mutableCopy];`

Comment: @Llg - problem solved or not my bro/sister

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you so much it works! Can you please make it as an answer and explain why it works with the `mutableCopy`? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey: / setValue:forKey` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC in this case. Can you? That would also avoid this misleading error message (but not the error per se).

Comment: @Llg - check the updated answer

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary * item = self.carouselSource[index];` That's a cast, it doesn't transform a `NSDictionary` into a `NSMutableDictionary`. You can use `mutableCopy`, or call the init method: `initWithDictionary:` if your objects are not NSCopying compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary is **immutable** - it's an **NSDictionary** and not an **NSMutableDictionary**.if you want to convert any(array, dictionary) **immutable** to **mutable** use **mutableCopy** for full conversion(balance the retain count).

```
NSMutableDictionary * item = [self.carouselSource[index] mutableCopy];
if([Utils isNull:[item objectForKey:@"image"]]) {
[item setObject:@"default_image.png" forKey:@"image"]; 
 }
```

instead of

```
 NSDictionary * item = self.carouselSource[index];
if([Utils isNull:[item valueForKey:@"image"]]) {
[item setValue:@"default_image.png" forKey:@"image"]; 
}
```