# Flutter App works perfectly on simulator (Iphone 12 mini) but crashes on device (Iphone 8 plus)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I am running my app on the simulator, and it runs well, but when I try running it on my device I get a bunch of errors:

```
(lldb) 2021-05-02 00:01:22.562844-0700 Runner[27185:7965723] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
7.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.                                           
-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28014d880
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28014d880'
*** First throw call stack:                                             
(0x1a2c85114 0x1b64abcb4 0x1a2b959b8 0x1a2c87758 0x1a2c896cc 0x10793b9a8 0x1a3e5d6e0 0x1a3fc5344 0x1a3fc69fc 0x1a3e5d944 0x1a3e64b28 0x1a3e64740 0x10793b82c 0x105626470 0x105626164 0x1a28bd298 0x1a28be280 0x1a289a4fc 0x1a289afe8 0x1a28a4808 0x1e85685a4 0x1e856b874)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #3, queue = 'com.google.FIRCoreDiagnostics', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001cd5fb95c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:                                  
->  0x1cd5fb95c <+8>:  b.lo   0x1cd5fb978               ; <+36>         
    0x1cd5fb960 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!                   
    0x1cd5fb964 <+16>: mov    x29, sp                                   
    0x1cd5fb968 <+20>: bl     0x1cd5d91dc               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

Here are the dependencies for my app:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  firebase_core: ^1.0.4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.1
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.6
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.3
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0-1.0.nullsafety.1
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.2
  cloud_functions: ^1.0.4
  image_cropper: 1.2.1
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.2
  location: ^4.1.1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.1
  bordered_text: ^1.0.1
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.0
  wechat_assets_picker: ^5.1.3
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  uuid: ^3.0.4
```

I have tried flutter clean, but no luck.
Any help or advice would be great!

Comment: [may be this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731353/nsdictionaryi-setobjectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: Did you enable background modes and push notifications via xcode?

Comment: have you taken internet permission?

Answer (score 1):

Delete Podfile.lock then `flutter run`